# Scrolling at ReactJs in IE-11 shows extra bar at right side

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I created a ReactJS app in IE-11. I want to scroll at a certain point programmatically.
every things are Ok, but when scroll occurred, an unpleasant scrollbar appears in right-side and all my design become damage.
how can I prevent this?

Before scroll:

[image]

After scroll:

[image]

my code to scroll:

```
const refFirstPoint = useRef(null);
refFirstPoint.current.scrollIntoView();

<div>
    <span ref={refFirstPoint}>{timeAM_PM(i)}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't completely understand, do you want to hide the scroll bar?

Comment: yes, actually i hide it by default, but then i scroll to certain element in my container programmatically, the scroll bar appeared again.

Comment: How did you hide it? Does it only appear again in IE, have you tested other browsers?

Comment: I hide this using css. i test that in other browsers like chrome and Firefox and all things are ok. i have this issue just in ie-11 and my app should be run in ie-11.

Comment: i hide scroll bar using '-ms-overflow-style: none;'

Comment: Your method is not recommended. You must not hide a scrollbar if there's content to scroll. You can personalize it but you don't have to hide it. "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style

Comment: I agree with you and also i've tried to show scroll bar, after that the vertical scrollbar for my content was appeared. but in this situation also my previous extra bar for whole height screen will appeared again.

Comment: Have you tried to use two div containers like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll/16671476#16671476)? The examples in the answer can hide the scroll bar and still be able to scroll well in browsers. I think the issue might be related to the styles you used instead of the scroll function. It could be better if you share a minimal, reproducible example which can be tested.

Comment: Yes, I tried this one. the problem is so ridiculous. the whole HTML tag shift to left about 14px. I don't know what is the problem. is it related to IE-11 or react in IE-11?  I don't have any issue in other browsers like chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. for solving this issue apply these changes:

In parent div, we hide scroll-bar and for preventing showing it again when we change child scrollbar position programmatically: set its box limit to `-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0`

```css
#parent_div:{
overflow: hidden; 
-ms-scroll-limit:0 0 0 0; /*plays a vital role*/
}
```

In child div, we hide scrollbar and control a scroll-bar programmatically.

```css
#child_div:{
scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox 64 */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 11 */
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /** Webkit */
    display: none;
  }
}
```